# Auto expanding columns

Tags: css, layout, css-position, column-width

I have 3 columns below the header. They are Left Side bar,content and Right side bar.
i want the height of the columns to increase according to the height of the tallest column.
For Example, If one of the columns is 400 px in height, i want the remaining two columns to have the same height.

I tried lot of css code but none of them work.
Can someone Please show me the required CSS code to get the above layout..??
Thank You.

[image: Auto Expanding columns.]

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options, this is one of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/7cc6m/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="left" class="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="right" class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#header, #footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#footer{ bottom: 0px; }

    #left.sidebar, #content, #right.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
}

#left.sidebar {
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}

#right.sidebar {
    right: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}

#content {
    left: 200px;
    right: 200px;
}
```

## CSS3

You can now use the flex-box attribute like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7cc6m/8/

```
#main {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex-box;
}

.sidebar {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    background: #e8e8e8;
    padding: 10px;
}

#content{
    -webkit-flex: 3;
    -ms-flex: 3;
    flex: 3;                
    background: #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Nice .. But there is a problem.
If the content inside one of the columns increases..all the columns should increase their height.This is not happening.

Just add some text to one of the columns and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least few methods.
Add add an new div as a container for "left" "center" "right" with overflow hidden and for your 3 divs set  padding-bottom: 20000px; margin-bottom: -20000px;